GitLab registry behind loadbalancer (HAProxy)
I'm trying to get a container registry in a self-hosted GitLab running behind a HAProxy Loadbalancer. If I try to do a docker login I get the error message "Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://registry.xxx.de/v2/ failed with status: 503 Service Unavailable"
Would be great if somebody could give me a hint into the right direction, as I'm looking for a solution since some days :-(
Server A (HAProxy)
global
  stats socket /tmp/api.sock user haproxy group haproxy mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
  log stdout format raw local0 info

defaults
  mode http
  timeout client 10s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 10s
  timeout http-request 10s
  log global

frontend http_frontend
    bind *:80
    acl letsencrypt-acl path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
    use_backend letsencrypt_backend if letsencrypt-acl
    default_backend gitlab_backend

backend letsencrypt_backend
    server letsencrypt acme-challenge-server:8080

frontend gitlab_front
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.xxx.de/haproxy.pem crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.xxx.de/haproxy.pem
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    use_backend gitlab_backend if { hdr(host) -i dev.xxx.de }
    use_backend registry_backend if { hdr(host) -i registry.xxx.de }

backend gitlab_backend
    server gitlab_server 90.11.111.52:80 check

backend registry_backend
    server gitlab_server 90.11.111.52:5050 check

Server B (GitLab)
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: 'dev.xxx.de'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://dev.xxx.de'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 5022
        letsencrypt['enable'] = false
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
          "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
          "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
        }
        registry_external_url 'http://registry.xxx.de'
        registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5000
        registry_nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
          "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
          "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
        }
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '5022:22'
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - './config:/etc/gitlab'
      - './logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - './data:/var/opt/gitlab'

